# How do I install software which has a GUI installer on AppVeyor?

Tags: powershell, installation, appveyor, energyplus

I'm trying to install required software for integration tests. I'm having trouble with my install script though since the installer doesn't have a silent mode. It's an EXE rather than an MSI if that makes a difference.

Here is what I have currently:

```
- ps: "curl $env:DOWNLOAD_URL -OutFile $env:TMP\\$env:DOWNLOADED_FILENAME"
- ps: "& $env:TMP\\$env:DOWNLOADED_FILENAME"
```

When I run this in PowerShell on my local machine it launches the installer but I can't see any way to send keys (I need to send something like `Alt+N, Alt+A, Alt+N, Alt+I, Alt+F`).

The installer is for [EnergyPlus](https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus/releases/download/v8.4.0-Update1/EnergyPlus-8.4.0-09f5359d8a-Windows-i386.exe) building energy simulation software.

Comment: Pretty much every exe installer has command line arguments. Can you let us know what installer are you trying to use? In general "/S" is a safe option to start with.

Comment: Edited to add a link - but it looks like `/S` is working. Thanks!

Comment: My experience is that starting with `installer.exe /help` will give a nice place to start. When `/help` does not exist there tends to be at least a useful error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `/S`, this works for most cases. If, however, the installer is async, you can do trick like this, to make powershell wait for installer to exit:

```
start "" /wait "EnergyPlus-8.4.0-09f5359d8a-Windows-i386.exe" /S
```

Comment: I used `- ps: "& $env:TMP\\$env:DOWNLOADED_FILENAME \S | Out-Null"` which also works to make powershell wait since it's doing something with the output.

Comment: More expressive notation of the powershell command: `Start-Process -FilePath "EnergyPlus-8.4.0-09f5359d8a-Windows-i386.exe" -ArgumentList "/S" -Wait`